# SNOWFLAKE convert BINARY to VARCHAR

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have BINARY field (visitor_id) that I want to convert to VARCHAR or NUMERIC (I think that is numeric value)  and print it in Snowflake

I Try this query:

```sql
select visitor_id, to_varchar(visitor_id) from table_X
```

so I have the same value `E55AE3B710EBAA89A96FEADEDB59AAE6CDC2000E` displayed
When I try:

```sql
select HEX_DECODE_STRING(to_varchar(visitor_id)) from table_X
```

I have this error :

> Invalid UTF8 detected while decoding
> 'E55AE3B710EBAA89A96FEADEDB59AAE6CDC2000E'

Could you please help me ?

Thanks
Regards,

Comment: You are getting this error because your query tries to get the characters from the bytes represented in your binary column. By default it uses utf-8, so if your string is not a valid utf8 data then you get this error. Could you please tell us what would be the expected output in your example. There is quite a difference between varchars and numerics

Comment: Hi aek, I would like to retrieve data stored in this field , not in binary form but in varchar or numeric ( i think it is numeric but not sure)

Comment: if you "want to avoid the error" use the `TRY_HEX_DECODE_STRING` version, you will then get null instead of an error, for the same reason as you get here, it will just not explode. Now if you have a numeric value encoded as binary, how it was encoded will need to be known to recover it.

Comment: @S.MAHIOU What is the value of [BINARY_INPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#label-binary-input-format)? To be able to decode the value you need to know how it was inserted and the default is HEX, but might have been changed in your case.